# RSAPrivateKey openssl C++ ios

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, openssl

Hi I using Openssl library in my iOS application I am able to write public pem but getting blank private key. here is my code -

```
char szModulus = "1162" ; 
char *szExp = "827655" ; 
RSA rsa1 = RSA_new(); 
int ret = BN_hex2bn(&rsa1->n,szModulus) ; 
ret = BN_hex2bn(&rsa1->d,szExp) ; 
FILE *fp; fp = fopen("/Users/ysi/Desktop/privateKey.pem", "wb"); 
PEM_write_RSAPrivateKey(fp, rsa1, NULL, NULL, 0, 0, NULL).
```

I am having modulus and exponents ans a parameter. Above code is not giving any error or warning.
Please help me. Why Pem is blank.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Did you generate the key?
In C RSA_new() doesn't generate a key it only allocates the memory for the key.
But I don't how it is in objective-C.

```
char szModulus = "1162" ; 
char *szExp = "827655" ; 
RSA* rsa1 = RSA_new(); 
/* added code */ 
BIGNUMBER* exp = BN_new();
BN_set_word(exp, 17);
RSA_generate_key_ex(rsa1, 1024, exp, NULL);
/* until here */
FILE *fp; fp = fopen("/Users/ysi/Desktop/privateKey.pem", "wb"); 
PEM_write_RSAPrivateKey(fp, rsa1, NULL, NULL, 0, 0, NULL).
```

Comment: Ok, What will be the possible changes in above code. Please guide me on C/C++ objective C supports both. Thank you.